# Align lines and dots with x-axis values in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a simple line chart visual using the d3.v4.min.js framework.

The visual looks like:

[image]

As you can see my problem is the alignment of the lines and their dots with the x-axis.
Below you can find the code implemented. I would like both lines to start off from *Germany* and not from the y-axis. I am guessing that due to a categorical and not numerical x-axis, javascript cannot distinguish the starting point so it paints the lines from the y-axis.

```js
data=[{dValues: "Germany", m1Values: 3323936.920000017, m2Values: 1469934.4999999946},
{dValues: "Japan", m1Values: 11847615.030000022, m2Values: 4860290.499999991},
{dValues: "Nordic", m1Values: 10382965.910000034, m2Values: 4289934.389999997},
{dValues: "Spain", m1Values: 3449601.7199999965, m2Values: 1594701.149999997},
{dValues: "UK", m1Values: 28157182.22999989, m2Values: 12590207.999999987},
{dValues: "USA", m1Values: 47691372.99999974, m2Values: 18448120.5719999}]

// helper Function to round the displayed numbers
var roundNumber = function roundNumber(num, noPrecision){
//check if the string passed is number or contains formatting like 13%
if (/^[0-9.]+$/.test(num)) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num);
if (num >= 1000 && num < 1000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'K'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000 && num < 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'M'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'T'; // Add the abbreviation
}
}
return num;
};

// Step 1: set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60 }; //adjust left margin to show how y-axis +20 in bottom and left for X,Y axis titles
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Step 2: set the ranges for x, y axis
// var n = 21;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

//Line generator 1
var valueline1 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.dValues); })
.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.m1Values); })
.defined(function(d) {
if (isNaN(d.m1Values)) {
d.m1Values = 0;
}
return d.m1Values !== 0;
});
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);

//Line generator 2
var valueline2 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.dValues); })
.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.m2Values); })
.defined(function(d) {
if (isNaN(d.m2Values)) {
d.m2Values = 0;
}
return d.m2Values !== 0;
});
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the svg chart
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.dValues = d.dValues;
d.m1Values = +d.m1Values;
d.m2Values = +d.m2Values;
});

//xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dValues; }));
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.dValues; }));
//xScale.domain([data[0].dValues, data[data.length-1].dValues]);
//yScale.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }) ]);
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); })]);

var lines = svg.attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')'; });
//var lines = svg.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (xScale(d.dValues))  + ",0)"; });

//add valueline 1 path //append to lines or svg
lines.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", valueline1);

//add valueline 2 path
lines.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "red")
.attr("d", valueline2);

// Define the div for the tooltip
/* var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.html("tooltip")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("opacity", 0); */
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
.attr("class", "d3-tip")
.offset([-25, 0])
.html(function(d) { return d.dValues + ": " + roundNumber(d.m1Values);});
svg.call(tool_tip);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot1")
.attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d.dValues); })
.attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(d.m1Values); })
.attr("r", 5)
.on('mouseover', tool_tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot2")
.attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d.dValues) })
.attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(d.m2Values)})
.attr("r", 5);

svg.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m1Values) + ")")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
.style("fill", "black")
.text("Sum(Sales)");

svg.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m2Values)+ ")")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
.style("fill", "black")
.text("Sum(Margin)");

svg.append("g")
.classed("labels-group", true)
.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.classed("label", true)
.attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.dValues) - 20 + "px"; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.m1Values) - 10 + "px"; })
.text(function(d) { return roundNumber(d.m1Values); });

svg.append("g")
.classed("labels-group", true)
.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.classed("label", true)
.attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.dValues) - 20 + "px"; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.m2Values) - 10 + "px"; })
.text(function(d) { return roundNumber(d.m2Values); });

//Add x axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

// Add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")));

var legend = svg.append("g")
.attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
.attr("font-size", 10)
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.selectAll("g")
.data(["Sum(Sales)", "Sum(Margin)"])
.enter().append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#ffab00", "red"]);
legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", width - 19)
.attr("width", 19)
.attr("height", 19)
.attr("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", width - 24)
.attr("y", 9.5)
.attr("dy", "0.32em")
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
.line {
fill: none;
stroke: #ffab00;
stroke-width: 3;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot1 {
fill: #ffab00;
stroke: #fff;
}
.dot2 {
fill: red;
stroke: #fff;
}

.d3-tip {
line-height: 1;
padding: 6px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline;
font-size: 10px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
content: "\25BC";
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips specifically */
.d3-tip.n:after {
margin: -2px 0 0 0;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js" integrity="sha512-a+/SD0dbGeXTN4AA5F1dDZqsPvXKKyS1bvU2z5ElpKNJ4xQlOMUs/1+suA+j+kj5nAAya+VmT5HUKZmazluxVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Appreciate any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **xScale** with **correctXScale** for lines/dots/labels:

```
const correctXScale = d => xScale(d.dValues) + width / data.length / 2;
```

**xScale** does not work because you use a band scale

```js
data=[{dValues: "Germany", m1Values: 3323936.920000017, m2Values: 1469934.4999999946},
{dValues: "Japan", m1Values: 11847615.030000022, m2Values: 4860290.499999991},
{dValues: "Nordic", m1Values: 10382965.910000034, m2Values: 4289934.389999997},
{dValues: "Spain", m1Values: 3449601.7199999965, m2Values: 1594701.149999997},
{dValues: "UK", m1Values: 28157182.22999989, m2Values: 12590207.999999987},
{dValues: "USA", m1Values: 47691372.99999974, m2Values: 18448120.5719999}]

// helper Function to round the displayed numbers
var roundNumber = function roundNumber(num, noPrecision){
//check if the string passed is number or contains formatting like 13%
if (/^[0-9.]+$/.test(num)) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num);
if (num >= 1000 && num < 1000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'K'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000 && num < 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'M'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'T'; // Add the abbreviation
}
}
return num;
};

// Step 1: set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60 }; //adjust left margin to show how y-axis +20 in bottom and left for X,Y axis titles
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Step 2: set the ranges for x, y axis
// var n = 21;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

const correctXScale = d => {
  return xScale(d.dValues) + width / data.length / 2;
}

//Line generator 1
var valueline1 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return correctXScale(d); })
.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.m1Values); })
.defined(function(d) {
if (isNaN(d.m1Values)) {
d.m1Values = 0;
}
return d.m1Values !== 0;
});
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);

//Line generator 2
var valueline2 = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return correctXScale(d); })
.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.m2Values); })
.defined(function(d) {
if (isNaN(d.m2Values)) {
d.m2Values = 0;
}
return d.m2Values !== 0;
});
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the svg chart
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.dValues = d.dValues;
d.m1Values = +d.m1Values;
d.m2Values = +d.m2Values;
});

//xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dValues; }));
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.dValues; }));
//xScale.domain([data[0].dValues, data[data.length-1].dValues]);
//yScale.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }) ]);
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); })]);

var lines = svg.attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')'; });
//var lines = svg.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (xScale(d.dValues))  + ",0)"; });

//add valueline 1 path //append to lines or svg
lines.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", valueline1);

//add valueline 2 path
lines.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "red")
.attr("d", valueline2);

// Define the div for the tooltip
/* var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.html("tooltip")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("opacity", 0); */
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
.attr("class", "d3-tip")
.offset([-25, 0])
.html(function(d) { return d.dValues + ": " + roundNumber(d.m1Values);});
svg.call(tool_tip);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot1")
.attr("cx", function(d){ return correctXScale(d); })
.attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(d.m1Values); })
.attr("r", 5)
.on('mouseover', tool_tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot2")
.attr("cx", function(d){ return correctXScale(d) })
.attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(d.m2Values)})
.attr("r", 5);

svg.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m1Values) + ")")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
.style("fill", "black")
.text("Sum(Sales)");

svg.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m2Values)+ ")")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
.style("fill", "black")
.text("Sum(Margin)");

svg.append("g")
.classed("labels-group", true)
.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.classed("label", true)
.attr("x", function(d) { return correctXScale(d) - 20 + "px"; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.m1Values) - 10 + "px"; })
.text(function(d) { return roundNumber(d.m1Values); });

svg.append("g")
.classed("labels-group", true)
.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.classed("label", true)
.attr("x", function(d) { return correctXScale(d) - 20 + "px"; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.m2Values) - 10 + "px"; })
.text(function(d) { return roundNumber(d.m2Values); });

//Add x axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

// Add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")));

var legend = svg.append("g")
.attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
.attr("font-size", 10)
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.selectAll("g")
.data(["Sum(Sales)", "Sum(Margin)"])
.enter().append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#ffab00", "red"]);
legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", width - 19)
.attr("width", 19)
.attr("height", 19)
.attr("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", width - 24)
.attr("y", 9.5)
.attr("dy", "0.32em")
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
.line {
fill: none;
stroke: #ffab00;
stroke-width: 3;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot1 {
fill: #ffab00;
stroke: #fff;
}
.dot2 {
fill: red;
stroke: #fff;
}

.d3-tip {
line-height: 1;
padding: 6px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline;
font-size: 10px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
content: "\25BC";
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips specifically */
.d3-tip.n:after {
margin: -2px 0 0 0;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js" integrity="sha512-a+/SD0dbGeXTN4AA5F1dDZqsPvXKKyS1bvU2z5ElpKNJ4xQlOMUs/1+suA+j+kj5nAAya+VmT5HUKZmazluxVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elp Michael. I am new to D3 developing and you really helped my to figure this out. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with the data array and other dimentions, just use a point scale:

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
data = [{
    dValues: "Germany",
    m1Values: 3323936.920000017,
    m2Values: 1469934.4999999946
  },
  {
    dValues: "Japan",
    m1Values: 11847615.030000022,
    m2Values: 4860290.499999991
  },
  {
    dValues: "Nordic",
    m1Values: 10382965.910000034,
    m2Values: 4289934.389999997
  },
  {
    dValues: "Spain",
    m1Values: 3449601.7199999965,
    m2Values: 1594701.149999997
  },
  {
    dValues: "UK",
    m1Values: 28157182.22999989,
    m2Values: 12590207.999999987
  },
  {
    dValues: "USA",
    m1Values: 47691372.99999974,
    m2Values: 18448120.5719999
  }
]

// helper Function to round the displayed numbers
var roundNumber = function roundNumber(num, noPrecision) {
  //check if the string passed is number or contains formatting like 13%
  if (/^[0-9.]+$/.test(num)) {
    num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num);
    if (num >= 1000 && num < 1000000) {
      num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000);
      if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
        num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
      }
      num += 'K'; // Add the abbreviation
    } else if (num >= 1000000 && num < 1000000000) {
      num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000);
      if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
        num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
      }
      num += 'M'; // Add the abbreviation
    } else if (num >= 1000000000) {
      num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000000);
      if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
        num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
      }
      num += 'T'; // Add the abbreviation
    }
  }
  return num;
};

// Step 1: set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 60
}; //adjust left margin to show how y-axis +20 in bottom and left for X,Y axis titles
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Step 2: set the ranges for x, y axis
// var n = 21;

var xScale = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]).padding(0.5);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

//Line generator 1
var valueline1 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m1Values);
  })
  .defined(function(d) {
    if (isNaN(d.m1Values)) {
      d.m1Values = 0;
    }
    return d.m1Values !== 0;
  });
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);

//Line generator 2
var valueline2 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m2Values);
  })
  .defined(function(d) {
    if (isNaN(d.m2Values)) {
      d.m2Values = 0;
    }
    return d.m2Values !== 0;
  });
//.curve(d3.curveNatural);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the svg chart
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.dValues = d.dValues;
  d.m1Values = +d.m1Values;
  d.m2Values = +d.m2Values;
});

//xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dValues; }));
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.dValues;
}));
//xScale.domain([data[0].dValues, data[data.length-1].dValues]);
//yScale.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values); }) ]);
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return Math.max(d.m1Values, d.m2Values);
})]);

var lines = svg.attr('transform', function(d) {
  return 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')';
});
//var lines = svg.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (xScale(d.dValues))  + ",0)"; });

//add valueline 1 path //append to lines or svg
lines.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline1);

//add valueline 2 path
lines.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", valueline2);

// Define the div for the tooltip
/* var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.html("tooltip")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("opacity", 0); */
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .offset([-25, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.dValues + ": " + roundNumber(d.m1Values);
  });
svg.call(tool_tip);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot1")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m1Values);
  })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .on('mouseover', tool_tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot2")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m2Values)
  })
  .attr("r", 5);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m1Values) + ")")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .text("Sum(Sales)");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(data[data.length - 1].dValues) + 5) + "," + yScale(data[data.length - 1].m2Values) + ")")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .text("Sum(Margin)");

svg.append("g")
  .classed("labels-group", true)
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .classed("label", true)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues) - 20 + "px";
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m1Values) - 10 + "px";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return roundNumber(d.m1Values);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .classed("labels-group", true)
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .classed("label", true)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dValues) - 20 + "px";
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.m2Values) - 10 + "px";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return roundNumber(d.m2Values);
  });

//Add x axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

// Add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")));

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(["Sum(Sales)", "Sum(Margin)"])
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#ffab00", "red"]);
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 19)
  .attr("width", 19)
  .attr("height", 19)
  .attr("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
}


/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */

.dot1 {
  fill: #ffab00;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.dot2 {
  fill: red;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 6px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */

.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style northward tooltips specifically */

.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -2px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.min.js" integrity="sha512-a+/SD0dbGeXTN4AA5F1dDZqsPvXKKyS1bvU2z5ElpKNJ4xQlOMUs/1+suA+j+kj5nAAya+VmT5HUKZmazluxVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Indeed Gerardo the .scalePoint() also made the trick. To be honest I have been searching for this issue a couple of days now. And most of the tutorials on d3 line charts used a linear scale with dates on x-axis. At some point I came across to scalePoint() but since my data were categorical I didn't try it on my code. Thanks again for the tip (upvoted).

Comment: @NikSp no worries. Since you have a categorical variable on the x axis you should use an ordinal scale, in this case a point scale. Most of line charts use a time scale because time is the most common x variable. By the way, despite having a "line", you don't have a line chart: what you have is a dot plot where you decided (arbitrarily) to connect the dots.